# What's the difference between a Heap and a Loser Tree in external sorting?

Tags: sorting, language-agnostic

I felt that they are very similar to each other, except at some *concepts*. In external sorting their functions are basically the same, that is to find the minimal/maximal value in k *runs*. So are there some significant differences between them two ?

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, loser trees and heaps are quite similar. However, there are a few important distinctions. The loser tree, because it provides the loser of each match, will contain repeat nodes. Since the heap is a data-storing structure, it won't contain these redundancies. Another difference between the two is that the loser tree must be a full binary tree (because it is a type of tournament tree), but the heap does not necessarily have to be binary.

Finally, to understand a specific quality of the loser tree, consider the following problem:
Suppose we have k sequences, each of which is sorted in nondecreasing order, that are to be merged into one sequence in nondecreasing order. This can be achieved by repeatedly transferring the element with the smallest key to an output array. The smallest key has to be found from the leading elements in the k sequences. Ordinarily, this would require k − 1 comparisons for each element transferred. However, with a loser tree, this can be reduced to log2 k comparisons per element.

Source: Handbook of Data Structures and Applications, Dinesh Mehta